# C# Mysql Client Server App. How should I manage online users?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

So I have an application which can be run on multiple clients, each accessing the central server for data. On the client apps, the user will need to login wih their credentials to access the program. I store the online users in a table in my database. My current method of managing online users is as follows:

A user logins in and a record of this is inserted into the online table in the database

```
MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection(Class1.connString);
MySqlCommand command = connection1.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO online (ComputerIP, ComputerName, Username, Time) " + "VALUES (@ip, @compname, @user, @datetime)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", getIP().NullString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compname", GetFQDN().NullString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", DateTime.Now);

connection1.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection1.Close();
```

As soon as they logout or exit the app, code is run to delete this record from the table.

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Class1.connString);
conn.Open();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM online WHERE ID='" + userID + "'", conn);

MySqlDataReader Reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();

conn.Close();
```

However, if the user was to shutdown the program incorrectly (End task, force shutdown computer, power outage), the code to remove this record is not executed, and as a result the user remains as logged on despite not being logged on.

How can I cover these situations? Is my approach to this practical or are there better solutions to this?

Comment: Where do you run this code parts exactly? On an event or something? By the way, there is no point to use `ExecuteReader` for a `DELETE` statement since it does _not_ return any data. You need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for it as well. Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Comment: Right, noted. I run the first block in a method on the login button press. The logout code is run when the main form closes, in the form closing event.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see how you can get around it, but maybe you should explain what it is you are trying to achieve? If you just want to know who is currently logged in can you get what you need from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST view?  This should update when a connection is closed for whatever reason.

Comment: I want to store the currently logged on users, so that a specific user will not be able to log in on two separate clients at the same time. So if he is logged in on one client, we store a record in the database (Computer IP, Computer Name, Username, Time of login), which will prevent him from logging in simultaneously on another pc. This is really important for my case. Is INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST suitable for my case? It seems that there's no way to distinguish who logged in using this method. It only shows the database user and host.

Comment: Each user in my program uses the same Database User 'root'.

Comment: In that case I don't think it will help.  I'm not a MySql expert but could you possibly do something with global variables?

Comment: I don't really see how that can help.